# How can I access appdata and private properties via Google Drive API across apps on different platforms?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-chrome-app, google-drive-android-api

I've created a Chrome App that uses the Google Drive API to store and modify files in Google Drive. I'm storing config data in the appdata folder, and proprietary file data using private properties at the file level. How can I now access the same appdata and private property data from an Android app and/or a desktop app?

My understanding is that access is based on the client id created in the Google API console. In setting up a "project" on the API console, each platform seems to need its own ClientID. So  I'll end up with a different ClientID for my Chrome App, my Android App and my Desktop App. But I can only use one ClientID when configuring the Drive SDK. So, is it possible to create an "App" that can access the same appdata and private property data across different platforms? If so, how should the each version of the app be configured on the Google API Console?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to have a single project for the different platforms. What makes you think you can't?

Comment: True, but when you configure the Drive SDK for that project, you can only provide a single ClientID for automatic OAuth 2.0 flow. So would the solution require NOT using the automatic OAuth 2.0 flow via the Drive SDK configuration?

Comment: You should have a single ClientID for all of your clients.  Once the user authorizes your app on one platform, there is no need for them to do it again.